# How To Load "Lazy" Modules Programmatically In Angular App?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have a monolithic Angular 15 app that *does not use the Router*.  The number of components inside it is growing and I'd like to break most of the components off into a separate module and load them separately.

My app already has a splash screen with a "loading" progress bar that advances as it fetches data from the server.  I want the main AppModule to contain a minimal set of components to get things started then I'll load the rest of the components as one of the startup tasks monitored by the progress bar.

The current state of things...

*app.module.ts:*

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatSidenavModule} from "@angular/material/sidenav";

import {SharedModule} from "./shared.module";

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ResizeableSidenavDirective} from "../components/resizeable-sidenav.directive";
import {SplashScreenComponent} from "../components/splash-screen/splash-screen.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SplashScreenComponent,
        ResizeableSidenavDirective,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*shared.module.ts:*

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {LeafletModule} from "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet";

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {MapViewComponent} from "../components/map-view/map-view.component";
import {Toaster} from "../components/toaster";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MapViewComponent,
        Toaster,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CommonModule,
        LeafletModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MapViewComponent,
        Toaster,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

*lazy.modules.ts:*

```
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {MatSliderModule} from "@angular/material/slider";

import {SharedModule} from "./shared.module";

... big list of component imports ...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyFirstComponent,
        MySecondComponent,
        MyThirdComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MyFirstComponent,
        MySecondComponent,
        MyThirdComponent,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

While the question I'd like to ask is how to do the lazy-load from within the splash screen, I can't even get the above to build.  There are many build errors from the `LazyModule` components saying things like:

> 'mat-slider' is not a known element

(yet MatSliderModule is an included import of LazyModule)

> No pipe found with name 'number'.

(yet CommonModule is also an included import)

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

(yet FormsModule is an included import)

> 'my-second' is not a known element:

(lazy component MyFirstComponent's HTML referencing MySecondComponent)

All of the above problems go away if I add `LazyModule` after `SharedModule` in the `AppModule` imports.  Oddly enough, it'll also build with just the import of `./lazy.module` even without adding `LazyModule` to the "imports" list.  But, of course, this returns me to the single, monolithic `main.js` file that I'm trying to break up.  So two questions:

*How do I detach `LazyModule` from `AppModule` and have it build?*

<strike>*What call do I make in my initialization to load LazyModule and how do I get notified that the loading is complete?*</strike>

**Update1:** I managed to fix the first error (`mat-slider` not known) by moving the import of `MatSliderModule` from `lazy.module` to `shared.module`.  This makes no sense to me since `mat-slider` isn't used anywhere but by the one lazy component.  This technique did not help with "number pipe not found" (`CommonModule`) or "can't bind ngModel" (`FormsModule`).

Comment: check this [link](https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093) about load non-routable modules. With standalone components check this [another link](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/routing-and-lazy-loading-with-standalone-components/)

Comment: The second link still uses the Router but the first looks to have the needed info on non-router loading (i.e. `NgModuleFactoryLoader`) though despite the article being from 2019 it appears out-of-date for Angular 13 as the shown `angular.json` change completely breaks the build.  It's probably enough to answer the second question; now I just need to figure out the answer to the first.

Comment: [Lazy-load directive](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/lazy-loading/src/lazy-load/lazy-load.directive.ts) / [Usage](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/lazy-loading)

Comment: Don't see anything significantly different than why I posted above so doesn't explain the build errors.

Comment: I added an update in case that gives any hints as to my build problems.

Comment: Where are the details on how you solved the lazy loading. Can you add this essential part to your question? Maybe you should consider adding a Stackblitz to your question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I haven't solved anything besides managing to get rid of one of the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eugene gave a very good answer and it was of great help in figuring out what I wanted to do.

My question, as phrased, was not actually what I wanted to know.  It should have been something like:

*Can I break my source code into parts such that I can download the essentials first and the rest later during a "splash" startup sequence?*

The short answer to that question is "no".  My investigations revealed that there *may* be a long answer that revolves around include/exclude directives in the `angular.json` file but it seemed complicated with likely maintenance headaches and generally counter to the designs of Angular.

In the end, I used the built-in Angular support to create and load modules.  What I'll present below is not significantly different than snippets I found elsewhere.  None of those ever made sense to me, however, because I was missing a very fundamental concept that everyone seemed to take for granted:

**Separation of code into independently loaded javascript files is *automatic*.**

Angular simply does this for you.  Unlike C/C++ where you manually group files into `.a` libraries or Java into `.jar` files, with Angular you just *don't explicitly instantiate anything you want to load separately*.  It can be *imported* in order to access fields and methods off of the classes so long as there is no direct creation of `new` objects of that type.

Whether components are grouped into modules or declared `standalone:true`, the trick is to simply not reference them directly.  Independent pieces are collected into separate `.js` files, including code from `node_modules` used only by them, which can then be loaded on-demand (aka "lazy loading").

Here's an example:

*publish.module.ts:*

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

import {PublishStartComponent} from "./publish-start/publish-start.component";
import {PublishContinueComponent} from "./publish-continue/publish-continue.component";
import {PublishFinalComponent} from "./publish-final/publish-final.component";
import {PublishResultsComponent} from "./publish-results/publish-results.component";
import {RegionPlacerComponent} from "./region-placer.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PublishStartComponent,
        PublishContinueComponent,
        PublishFinalComponent,
        PublishResultsComponent,
        RegionPlacerComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,  // |number
        FormsModule,   // ngModel
    ]
})
export class PublishModule {
    getPublishStartFactory()    { return PublishStartComponent    }
    getPublishContinueFactory() { return PublishContinueComponent }
    getPublishFinalFactory()    { return PublishFinalComponent    }
    getPublishResultsFactory()  { return PublishResultsComponent  }
    getRegionPlacerFactory()    { return RegionPlacerComponent    }
}
```

In Angular 15, Lazy-loading the file and getting access to this is just two lines:

```
    const {PublishModule} = await import ("../../components/publish/publish.module")
    const pminstance = createNgModule(PublishModule, this.injector).instance
```

Then the classes can be instantiated by using the "factory" return types:

```
    let thing = new (pmintstance.getPublishStartFactory())(...)
```

Or it can be passed to functions needing a type:

```
    this.dialogService.open(pmintstance.getPublishStartFactory(), {...})
```

In my case, it looks like this:

*myapp.ts:*

```
...
import {PublishModule} from "../../components/publish/publish.module";
...
@Component({...})
export class MyApp {
    ...
    private pmInstance: PublishModule|undefined
    ...
    constructor(dialogService: MatDialog, injector: Injector) {...}
    ...
    private async onPublishButtonFirstClick() {
        const {PublishModule} = await import ("../../components/publish/publish.module")
        this.pmInstance = createNgModule(PublishModule, this.injector).instance

        let dref = this.dialogService.open(this.pmInstance.getPublishStartFactory(), {
            ...
        })

        dref.afterClosed().subscribe((rid: string) => {
            if (rid == null || rid == "") return
            this.regionName = dref.componentInstance.regionName
            this.regionProjection = dref.componentInstance.regionType
            this.imageUrl = dref.componentInstance.imageUrl!
            this.imageSize = dref.componentInstance.imageSize!

            const rpc = document.getElementById("overlay-container")!
            const injector = Injector.create({
                providers: [
                    {provide: 'imageUrl', useValue: this.imageUrl!},
                    {provide: 'imageSize', useValue: this.imageSize!},
                ]
            })
            this.regionPlacerView = this.injector.get<ViewContainerRef>(ViewContainerRef);
            const rp = this.regionPlacerView.createComponent(this.pmInstance!.getRegionPlacerFactory(), {
                injector: injector
            })

            this.regionPlacer = rp.instance
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

There's more to all this, such as creating "shared" modules for those components used by both the base code and the lazy code but nothing needs to be changed with regard to how it's used.  Simply access the components of the shared module normally within both base/lazy sides and Angular will take care of doing the right thing (in this case: splitting "shared" into its own file but loading it as part of `index.html`).

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this!  It's really hard to find info on this topic, as pretty much everything else out there is either outdated, just dynamically loading components that are all included in the initial bundle, or doing lazy-loading but only based on routes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Lazy loading without routing.

You can load all the components lazy without routing.
All you need is to manually resolve component factory and compile component.
For angular 13 it is more automatic and code looks something like:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("formComponent", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  formComponent!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler, private injector: Injector) {}

  async loadForm() {
    const { LazyFormModule } = await import("./lazy-form.component");
    const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(
      LazyFormModule
    );
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.getComponent();
    this.formComponent.clear();
    this.formComponent.createComponent(componentFactory, {ngModuleRef: moduleRef});
  }
}

export class LazyFormModule {
  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  getComponent() {
    return LazyFormComponent
  }
}
```

For more examples, check  https://www.wittyprogramming.dev/articles/lazy-load-component-angular-without-routing/ or https://medium.com/@ckyidr9/lazy-load-feature-modules-without-routing-in-angular-9-ivy-220851cc7751

2. Manage your lazy loading logic.

To make things work I recommend you to leave only blank app with splash screen and remove all the dependent modules (for example, comment them). Then add lazy loaded modules one-by-one, using the technique from 1st part. All the required modules should go to the lazy modules, not to the app module.

3. Shared modules.

Only then if you see some repeating modules you should add lazy shared modules for common logic (dont use it in app too).

Comment: (BTW, I've moved to Angular 15)  I can move all but six of my components to `lazy.module.ts` without an error.  I've left the problematic six in `app.module.ts` for now.  It builds (and runs) but everything still goes into the one monolithic `main.js` file with all the components in it.  How is build even finding "lazy"?

Since the plan is to load everything during the splash/progress screen anyway, really I just need to fetch a minimal `main.js` file as part of `index.html` and the rest will loaded during startup before the main app begins to run.  There is no on-demand loading.

Comment: it is not enought to move logic to lazy module, you should use approach from first part of answer, `componentFactoryResolver`, `compileModuleAsync`, `moduleFactory.create(this.injector)`, `createComponent`, etc

Comment: your case is on-demand too, but demand is not a click or an action, but a component init

Comment: The "first part" doesn't talk about the `.module.ts` configuration.  The linked example defines an `@NgModule` with the lazy component.  I'm saying that even when I do that, the component still ends up in `main.js` and is available just as before without any lazy-load logic.

Comment: if you do this https://medium.com/@ckyidr9/lazy-load-feature-modules-without-routing-in-angular-9-ivy-220851cc7751
and load lazy module on demand it will not be in main.js.
I've done this in multiple apps.
Be patient about lazy module with lazy component.
It should not be included to app module. 
It should be imported and injected manuallly on demand.

Comment: You are confused by your lazy and shared module. Comment it all out. Leave blank working app and add simple lazy module with lazy component with load and inject by demand as in example, only then when lazy loading works, move your logic with material and other modules.

Comment: the only place with lazy module import is const { LazyFormModule } = await import("./lazy-form.component"); in my example or  import('./lazy-feature/lazy-feature.module').then(({ LazyFeatureModule }) in article.
If you check console the script loads on demand (for example, app component init)

Comment: Do I actually have to _remove_ the code and then add it back later?  The un-included components still get compiled because they're in the source-tree (which answers my earlier question about why they're found when the lazy.module wasn't referenced).  Somewhat related: What about all the typescript classes that _aren't_ components?  (I can't help but feel that I'm missing something fundamental here.)

Comment: I recommend to remove the secondary code to clearly control what is imported where and to reduce the issue scope. Even if lazy loading code is ok, you can get issues with dependent modules and you can add it not properly, shared code makes it more complicated.

If code is not imported, it will not be in build result, no matter module, component or class.
First, ts compiles to js, then ng compiles aot, then webpack bundles it and uses tree shaking.

Comment: If code is imported lazy (via router or not), its module and content will be in separate chunk.

Comment: You have two issues, solve them separately.
1) Make lazy loading work on dummy component
2) Resolve secondary (material, forms, etc) module imports on working lazy load

Comment: Okay.  This is turning out to be too much effort for me to work on right now.  I'll come back to it when I have some idle time.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brian White Did you look at my comment? It's easy and works

Comment: **Working!**  But...  `Compiler` is deprecated in Angular 15: "Ivy JIT mode doesn't require accessing this symbol."  `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated in Angular 15: "Angular no longer requires Component factories. Please use other APIs where Component class can be used directly."  Error doing import: "ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule 'MeasureModule' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'."  (Fixed by adding @NgModule header to exported `LazyFormModule` class.)  Will see about removing/replacing deprecated classes later.

Comment: Didnt know about deprecation in 15, thx. Fair to mention, answer was written for ng 14. Thx for info for v15.

Comment: (Bounties used to be assigned automatically.)  Let's complete the answer and then I'll accept it.  The A15 methodology without the deprecated compiler is `const moduleRef = createNgModule(LazyFormModule, this.injector)`.  The "something fundamental" that I felt I didn't understand seems to be that the splitting of code into separate files is implicit in how they're loaded rather than in how the modules are defined.  For an old hack like myself, this is counterintuitive.  If you agree, add that to the answer, too, as I think it would be helpful to those trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: #2 isn't as easy as it sounds.  Because the splitting of js out of main.js is implicit based on how the components are referenced (directly or via a method on the module object), it's not possible to take components, move them to a new module, and tell the splash screen to import them.  All references to those components inside "non-lazy" code (even though that code won't run until later) would also have to be removed and instead get "factory" versions via module methods.  Either I need some way to split `main.js` into chunks by paths or I need to refactor things a lot, probably the latter.